# C# and SQL simple authetication (visual studio)

Tags: c#, sql, authentication

I have a problem with simple authetication. I create database with users name and password, on html I set two textbox. In database i have a one record (admin,admin).
This is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString());

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    string query = "select * from [Usery] where Login='" + login.Text + "' and Pass='" + pass.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    if (output == "1")
    {
        Session["user"] = login.Text;
        Response.Write("Good");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Error");
    }             
}
```

And connectionstring:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connect" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\User.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I click start I try login with admin/admin, but on browser i have message like in my else: Error.

In visual studio 0 error, 0 warning.

I think it's trivial. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code has a huge security vulnerability. You need to fix it. You're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Visit [this site](http://bobby-tables.com/) for information on what that means and how to fix it.

Comment: Error information?

Comment: Try `Select 1` instead of `Select *`. Please keep in mind that `ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty (username and/or password incorrect)

Comment: haha, Thak You @Rui Jarimba !!!

Comment: @Dejmian keep in mind what mason wrote, your code is subject to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you may change your query to something like below, keeping rest of the code as-is

```
string query = "select count(1) from [Usery] where Login='" + Trim(login.Text) + "' and Pass='" + pass.Text + "'";
```

Also, as already advised by @mason, the approach you've taken is prone to SQL Injection attacks. Read about it in detail, and go for stored procedures instead